# Select users from table foreach repeated id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

I have this table:
users

```
id    |    name
---------------------
1     |    Lisa
2     |    John
```

and i have this users list:

```
 (1,2,2,2,1,2)
```

and i want to get this result:

```
 Lisa,John,John,John,Lisa,John
```

how i can get this result just using SQL query in my Phpmyadmin without using PHP?
i must use Left Join ?

Comment: The list is a string?

Comment: i have another database names orders. this string exported from that table

Comment: What is a "list"?  That is not a data structure in MySQL.

Comment: @Ebadghafoory: The other database is on the same server? If so you'd rather just join the two tables.

Comment: @stickybit yes, same server and same database

Comment: @stickybit sorry, i reply your last question wrong, "orders" table in the same database of my "users" table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming orders table is on the same server) You should use inner join here. Because, there should be an user to have an entry in orders table.

```
SELECT abc = STUFF(( Select user.user_name + ',' from 
orders inner join users on users.id = orders.user_id where orders.user_id in (your string of user ids) for 
xml_path(' ')), 1, 1, '') FROM temp1
```